# PostgreSQL - Help Required in Creating View

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, select, view

I'm creating a view here.

Here's a example.

**Table1 :**

```
time,date,label,count
12:00 AM,1-Jan,A,10
12:30 AM,1-Jan,A,10
1:00 AM,1-Jan,A,19
1:30 AM,1-Jan,B,14
2:00 AM,1-Jan,B,18
2:30 AM,1-Jan,B,13
3:00 AM,1-Jan,C,20
3:30 AM,1-Jan,C,16
4:00 AM,1-Jan,C,12
4:30 AM,1-Jan,D,10
5:00 AM,1-Jan,D,16
5:30 AM,1-Jan,D,18
```

**Table2 :**

```
label,category
A,Apple
B,Ball
C,Cat
E,Elephant
```

**VIEW:**

```
time,date,label,category,count
12:00 AM,1-Jan,A,Apple,10
12:30 AM,1-Jan,A,Apple,10
1:00 AM,1-Jan,A,Apple,19
1:30 AM,1-Jan,B,Ball,14
2:00 AM,1-Jan,B,Ball,18
2:30 AM,1-Jan,B,Ball,13
3:00 AM,1-Jan,C,Cat,20
3:30 AM,1-Jan,C,Cat,16
4:00 AM,1-Jan,C,Cat,12
4:30 AM,1-Jan,D,   ,10
5:00 AM,1-Jan,D,   ,16
5:30 AM,1-Jan,D,   ,18
```

**View SCRIPT :**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW queue_interval_wise AS 
SELECT
    t1.Time,
    t1.Date,
    t1.Label,
    t2.Category,
    t1.Count
FROM Table1 t1, Table2 t2
WHERE t1.Label = t2.Table2
```

When I run that script i get more number of rows than the number of rows in `Table1`.

Whether I use `WHERE` clause or `LEFT JOIN` the result is not matching the numbers of rows of `Table1`.

Someone let me know where i'm doing the mistake.

Comment: What do you *expect* to happen? Your listed view output *does* have the same number of rows (12) as table1, so it was clearly created with a query using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, not the inner join query you posted above. I do not understand what you think the problem here is, or what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW queue_interval_wise AS 
SELECT DISTINCT 
    t1.Time,
    t1.Date,
    t1.Label,
    IFNULL(t2.Category, ''),
    t1.Count
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.Label = t2.Label
```

Comment: It's still now matching the numbers of rows on the `Table1`

Comment: Even the `DISTINCT` didn't help me out.

Comment: When I just select the few columns of the `Table1` I actually don't get the same numbers of rows. But when I do `SELECT * FROM Table1` I get the exact number of rows.

Comment: @user2549787 Update the output data which you're getting.

Comment: This was a sample data i created myself. In this I get the exact number of rows. But in the actual data when I use `LEFT JOIN` the number of rows is greater than the `Table1`. Any idea where the mistake would've been happen?

Comment: @user2549787: if you have more than one row in table2 with the same label this is an expected behaviour of any join.

Comment: Try select count(*), label from Table2 group by label having count(*) >1. Also, you have "WHERE t1.Label = t2.Table2". Shouldn't it be "WHERE t1.Label = t2.label"